# Is there a way to prevent accidental dragging and dropping in Windows Explorer or on the server side?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-11

Last week somebody accidentally dragged a folder into another folder on our network drive. This happens now and then, it has happened to me as well. The network drive is an Ubuntu Samba / SMB drive.

Explorer should be limited by having to select a file or folder first before you can drag it. Is it possible to force this behavior? We work mostly with Windows 10, some laptops are upgraded to Windows 11.

On the server side maybe the root folders (of the network drive) could be protected somehow, but this has its downsides. Any tips are welcome though.